# Gitolite отказывается работать по ssh

Tags: ubuntu, git

`Gitolite` отказывается работать по `ssh`

Сервер

> -UBUNTU

Клиент

> -Win7

На сервере:

- пользователь `gitroot`
- установлен `git` на дефолтных настройках
- установлен `gitolite` на дефолтных настройках
- сгенерированы ключи `ssh` на дефолтных установках
- файл `sshd_config` поправлен:

  раскоментированы строчки

> RSAAuthentication yes
>
> PubkeyAuthentication yes

- создан пользователь `git`
- Копирован свой публичный `ssh rsa` ключ из домашней директории для настройки управления репозиторием

> sudo cp ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub /home/git/admin.pub

- Заходим под пользователем git и заканчиваем настройку

> sudo su git
>
> cd
>
> gl-setup admin.pub

На клиенте:

- сгенерированы ключи через `GitBash`
- скопирован публичный ключ на сервер через `GitBash`

> git clone ssh://git@server:/home/git/repositories/gitolite-admin.git

Спрашивает пароль для пользователя `git`, хотя не должно по инструкции. Что это может быть? Ведь при создании пользователя git не нужно было вводить никаких паролей??

Если при создании пользователя git задать пароль то все отлично клонируется на локальную машину. Только вот push выдает такое:

> $ git push origin master git@server password: Counting
> objects: 4, done. Delta compression using up to 4 threads. Compressing
> objects: 100% (3/3), done. Writing objects: 100% (4/4), 358 bytes | 0
> bytes/s, done. Total 4 (delta 1), reused 0 (delta 0) remote: ENV GL_RC
> not set remote: BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at hooks/update line
> 20. remote: error: hook declined to update refs/heads/master To ssh://git@server:/home/git/repositories/gitolite-admin.git  !
> [remote rejected] master -> master (hook declined) error: failed to
> push some refs to
> 'ssh://git@server:/home/git/repositories/gitolite-admin.git'

Comment: Какой командой создавали пользователя? Пробовали ли задать пароль (`passwd git`)?

Comment: Обновил вопрос. Там про пароль детально

Comment: `/home/git/repositories/` - это правильный путь?

Comment: Да правильный потому что клонирование проходит гладко.

Comment: Вот здесь https://git-scm.com/book/ru/v1/%D0%9D%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B9%D0%BA%D0%B0-Git-%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D1%81-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%89%D1%8C%D1%8E-Git написано >>Сообщение "remote rejected" будет появляться для каждой отклонённой перехватчиком ссылки. Оно сообщает нам, что ссылка была отклонена именно из-за сбоя в перехватчике.

Comment: Дальше, боюсь, не подскажу.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

командой `gl-setup /путь/к/файлу/с/публичным/ключом`, выполненной от имени пользователя `git`, вы «настроили» этого пользователя на обслуживание инфраструктуры *gitolite* (которая этой же командой создана в домашнем каталоге этого пользователя).

изначально инфраструктура содержит всего один репозиторий `gitolite-admin`, через который и осуществляется управление: создание и удаление репозиториев, назначение прав доступа к ним и т.п.

публичный ключ, который вы передали параметром программе `gl-setup`, назначен при этом «административным».

при помощи **секретной** части этого ключа теперь можно склонировать репозиторий `gitolite-admin`, и, внеся в него изменения (например, добавив в файл `conf/gitolite.conf` описание нового репозитория), «запушить» эти изменения обратно (что приведёт к созданию того самого нового репозитория).

где «взять» эту **секретную** часть? там же, где вы «взяли» публичную:
вы упомянули команду `sudo cp ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub /home/git/admin.pub`, которую выполнили от имени какого-то пользователя. вот в домашнем каталоге этого неназванного пользователя и находится **секретная** часть ключа. в файле:

```
~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

---

что же дальше делать?

там же, на сервере, от имени того самого пользователя, чьей публичной частью ключа вы воспользовались при настройке *gitolite*, сделайте клон репозитория `gitolite-admin`:

```
$ cd
$ git clone git@server:gitolite-admin
$ cd gitolite-admin
```

и дальше управляйте *gitolite*-ом по инструкции.

---

например, если вам надо дать административные полномочия пользователю, владеющему **другой** парой из публичного и секретного ключа, то:

1. скопируйте новый публичный ключ в каталог `keydir` под именем, например, `admin2.pub`.
2. добавьте (через пробел) `admin2` в конец строки, начинающейся с `@adm =` в файле `conf/gitolite.conf` (это так группа *adm* описана).
3. добавьте эти файлы в *index*:

   ```
   $ git add conf/gitolite.conf keydir/admin2.pub
   ```
4. сделайте *commit*:

   ```
   $ git commit -m 'добавлен ключ admin2 в группу adm'
   ```
5. отправьте изменения *gitolite*-у:

   ```
   $ git push
   ```

---

p.s. а доступ по паролю к *gitolite*-у невозможен. только по ключу. потому у вас и ошибка происходит.

---

**дополнение про путь к репозиторию**

для правильного обращения к репозиториям, управляемым инфраструктурой *gitolite*, надо указывать лишь их имена.

на приведённом примере — не:

```
$ git clone ssh://git@server:/home/git/repositories/gitolite-admin.git
```

а:

```
$ git clone git@server:gitolite-admin
```

Comment: git clone ssh://git@server:/home/git/repositories/gitolite-admin.git;    Cloning into 'gitolite-admin'...
The authenticity of host '192.168.196.133 (192.168.196.133)' can't be established.
ECDSA key fingerprint is 64:b3:b7:fc:db:bd:e8:cc:6e:6e:5a:66:cf:bc:07:15.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
Warning: Permanently added '192.168.196.133' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.
R access for home/git/repositories/gitolite-admin DENIED to admin
(Or there may be no repository at the given path. Did you spell it correctly?)

Comment: @MARKSIST, я дополнил ответ информацией про путь.

Comment: на сервере получилось склонировать но в конце выдало ошибку Невозможно получить доступ '/home/gitroot/.config/git/attributes': отказано в доступе. Клонирую от имени главного пользователя ubuntu gitroot

Comment: `/home/gitroot` — откуда он тут взялся? это, видимо, домашний каталог пользователя *gitroot*. что это за пользователь? какое отношение он имеет к пользователю *git*?

Comment: Это главный пользователь сервера. у него секретная часть ключа.

Comment: а, понял. вы именно от его имени выполняете команду `git clone ...`? значит, упомянутый файл создан пользователем *root*. вы, судя по всему, чрезмерно «увлеклись» выполнением команд с помощью `sudo` и в домашнем каталоге пользователя *gitroot* сейчас есть файлы/каталоги, не принадлежащие самому пользователю. исправьте это с помощью команды: `sudo chown -R gitroot /home/gitroot`.

Comment: Если у меня 200 равноправных разработчика для одного репозитория  то мне в keydir необходимо добавить 200 разных пблик ключей? я правильно понимаю?

Comment: да, правильно. `имя.pub`, а в конфигурационном файле упоминаете как `имя`.